# QGIS text size of label is zero one decimal place if contains one decimal place

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm new here. I have version 3.16.3-Hannover at work and unfortunately I'm not allowed to update.

My QGIS has the following problem:
I enter a label for a layer with a text size that has one decimal place (e.g. 8.5).
[image: Setting before saving]

Then I save and close the project. And when opened the text size is set to 0.
[image: Setting after opening]

Are there settings for this or how can I solve the problem other than editing the qgs file afterwards.

Comment: Have you considered using 8 or 9 pt as text size? Have you tried changing you language to english and then saving/opening the project?

Comment: Yes, it works with 8 or 9, but the sizes are country specifications that we have to adhere to when creating maps. Unfortunately, changing the language didn't work either.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to set the font size by using a 'Datendefinierte Übersteurerung' (the button to the right of the field; Then: 'Bearbeiten'). This might override the value in the field. Note: There you will need to use a point instead of a comma.

Comment: The fact that the Data-defined override works means it is due to the transfer from the field. It also works with a new profile, so it's somewhere in my profile.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. It was due to the installed plugin “OSM Data Sync”. Because without the plugin, it keeps the text size with one decimal place

I reported an issue to the developer.
[OSM Data Sync - Issue #35](https://gitlab.com/geometalab/OSMDataSync/-/issues/35)